# How do I use group by with a default value?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have the following table:

```
+-----------+------------+-------+
| quiz_type | student_id | score |
+-----------+------------+-------+
| class     | NULL       | 10    |
+-----------+------------+-------+
| class     | NULL       | 9     |
+-----------+------------+-------+
| student   | A          | 5     |
+-----------+------------+-------+
| student   | B          | 7     |
+-----------+------------+-------+
| student   | A          | 6     |
+-----------+------------+-------+
```

I want to get the sum of the scores for each student, but need to include the class scores for every student. In other words, I would like a result table like:

```
+------------+-------+
| student_id | score |
+------------+-------+
| A          | 30    |
+------------+-------+
| B          | 26    |
+------------+-------+
```

In reality, the quiz_type column doesn't exist. I need to do a `GROUP BY student_id`, but include the `NULL` values with every group. I've been struggling with this for quite a bit. Is there a good solution?

Comment: Maybe the issue is that your database design needs refinement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select 
    student_id,
    sum(score) + (select sum(score) from yourtable where student_id is null) as score
from yourtable
where student_id is not null
group by `student_id`
```

[<kbd>SQLFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d9b4a/2)

Comment: i have same solution but i am slower

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What if I wanted to get the standard deviation of all the scores?

Comment: @areke This will be another question. :-(

Comment: @Drew what is the comment for?

Comment: You don't think you expanded the question? A [chamelion question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478), holding the gent hostage?

Comment: @Drew Oh, I accidentally used sum instead of standard deviation when I asked the question. I'm a new user, which means it won't let me post for 90 minutes, so I wanted to ask this (very related question, which makes it not a chameleon question) to find out if the solution were simple.

Comment: If you notice, I accepted the question as soon as I saw that he replied "This will be another question" because I didn't want to be unfair torwards him. Stack Overflow's mission is to `build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.` I don't think calling new users out for acceptable behavior is the right way to go - especially with a nondescript comment like "come on" which makes no effort to point out (what you thought) was unacceptable.

Comment: No, I noticed you accepted it 2 minutes after I badgered you :p

Comment: @Drew Yes, about a minute or two after you said "come on," as that's the same time that I saw his comment.